Do you see anything wrong with the power section in my schematic?
I am new to electrical engineering and I would be very grateful if someone could look over my schematic and tell me if something is wrong or could be done better. In my schematic I have a XT60-M connector for a LiPo battery of +12V. The AO3401A P-channel MOSFET is supposed to act as a reverse polarity protection (I chose a P-channel MOSFET over a SCHOTTKY diode after watching the video from Afrotechmods entitled "How to protect circuits from reversed voltage polarity!"). For the buck regulator (XL1509-5.0E) I tried to follow the manufacturer schematic, but I couldn't find the SCHOTTKY diode that they use in their schematic (1N5820) so I replaced it to the DSS34(below I posted a screenshot with my schematic and also the recommended schematic). Any insight is helpful! 


Please add information about the expected max output current you want to get.
And the part number of the inductor. Proper sizing of the inductor is important and with the provided info we can't have a lot to that.
And remember that the physical PCB layout plays a big role for the DC/DC. Feel free to ask for comments on that part once the routing is done

What is the real voltage range of your battery? Do you have protection from discharging the battery fully? How much current for 5V and 3.3V you intend to draw? We can't give any insight unless we know what the circuit is expected to be capable of.

Multiple datasheets for that AMS1117 state that the bypass caps should be tantalum, which are polarised, unlike your C14/C16. Ceramic might have too little ESR.

Also note that U3 will be wasting almost three times the amount of power as heat that your 3.3V supply is actually providing. You'd probably be better powering it from the 5V rail instead, though it depends on the actual power requirements.

I am not sure if this is for a hobby or a professional application but I would be very cautious with parts like this XL semi integrated switcher as a) all specs are at 25 °C without min and max at extreme values and b) there are no characterization curves. I could not say if this a voltage- or current-controlled circuit (but most likely VM) and there are no indication on the stability margins which usually heavily depend on the output capacitor equivalent series resistance. For tinkering yes, for volume production, euh, non!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@Blup1980 For the 5V buck converter I want to power 2 9g servos (from what I have seen each servo draws about 500mA to 750mA, so a maximum of 1.5A for both of them)  and with the 3.3V converter I want to power the rest of the circuit (STM32F405RGT6 MCU, BMP280, BMI088, w25n01gvzeig). I couldn't find a suitable inductor yet(from what I understood I am looking for a 68uH inductor with a saturation current of 2.3A or above with a DC resistance as small as possible). Thank you for your time!

@Justme I don't have the battery yet(I am looking for one to buy), but from what I understood a 12v battery wouldn't be suitable for my buck converter, so I think I will buy something like the GAONENG GNB 2S 7.4V 2300mAh 50C LiPo Battery XT60 Connector. For the 5v regulator I intend to draw about 1.5A (two 9 g servos) and for the 3.3V converter the power drawn would be very low (a few tens of mA I think for the STM32F405RGT6, BMP280, BMI088, w25n01gvzeig). Thank you for your response!

@Unimportant Thank you for your insight! I changed the unpolarized capacitors to polarized ones and I will be looking for tantalum caps.

@Finbarr It's a great idea, I am changing the schematic right now. Thank you for your help!

@VerbalKint For the moment it's more for a hobby. I am studying EECS first year and I work on a project to build a flight controller for a model rocket. Do you have a recommendation for a more reliable buck converter for 5V output and ~2 or more A? Thank you for your time!

@Robert I don't understand why you understood the 12V is not good for the buck converter. It's especially given in the example how you can make a 12V to 5V converter with it. Also instead of changing to tantalum caps, it may be cheaper to change the regulator into modern era than to change capacitors to match an old regulator. And if you intend to have a polarized battery connector, why waste energy into polarity protection if it is impossible to use wrong polarity by design.

@Robert, it is usually better to buy from reputable brands, especially if support or application notes are expected. There are plenty of choices for these buck switchers like TI, ST, MPS to cite a few. For instance, the old LM2596 is now an industry standard. Look at these specs and compare them with the one from XL semi : )

@Justme sorry I meant to say the P-channel MOSFET(A03401A) is not suited for 12V, but it doesn't matter now because I am taking it out. I didn't know the battery connector is polarized.

I see two things:

The abs max rating for VGS of the PMOS (AO3401A): The full input voltage will be seen across the source and gate of the MOSFET when it is on. The datasheet rating is ±12V so the operational VGS will be quite close to the abs max rating. Note that the battery will have higher voltage when it's full so the operational VGS will exceed the manufacturer ratings. This doesn't necessarily mean that the PMOS will die instantly, but it's always better to leave some margin between the operational values and the manufacturer's guaranteed limits.
Ferrite Bead on the power rail: No part number is given so I can't make any checks. All I can say is make sure the current rating is enough to handle rail currents.


I don't have the battery yet, so I think I will buy one such as the GAONENG GNB 2S 7.4V 2300mAh 50C LiPo Battery XT60 Connector which has a lower voltage and for the ferrite bead I am using the PB3216-601/3A0. Thank you for your insight!

@Robert There are plenty of PMOS devices with Vgs ratings of 20 V, so maybe it's more beneficial to change the PFET vs changing your plans for the battery.
